# Finding the electric field when the sphere has multiple charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

[image]

In this case, in part (d), why is the charge -Q on the surface of the sphere not taken into account?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused about the induced charges. Consider a conducting spherical shell with just a charge $+Q$ at its center. It induces a $-Q$ on the *inside* surface of the shell, and since the shell has to remain at a total charge of $0$, the outside surface has $+Q$ charge. The net charge seen from outside is still the same $+Q -Q + Q = 0$. You could view this as the $+Q$ charge "attracting electrons" from the shell towards itself (so they come to the inside surface), so the outside surface gets positively charged. But either way there is no charge on the shell in total.

In your case, the $+Q$ at the center will induce $-Q$ on the inside surface. Net charge on the sphere is $+2Q$ which implies that the outside surface will have $+2Q - (-Q) = +3Q$, which is what is used in the solution.

Comment: Why is the -Q being subtracted now?

Comment: The sphere should have total charge $2Q$. The inside surface has $-Q$. The outside surface must have $2Q - (-Q) = 3Q$.